# Require for a relative path across modules

Tags: node.js, path, fs

I have project `A` that has a `config.json` file in its root. The project has a dependency on external module B, calling `B.setConfig('./config.json')`.

While inside `B.setConfig(path)`, if I call `fs.existsSync(path)`, it says Ok, file exists, but calling `require(path)` fails with `Cannot find module "./config.json"`.

Is it possible to adjust the relative path while inside module `B` to make `require` work?

I would prefer not to call `setConfig` with the full path, as it makes things awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, eventually, that if we want to take a relative path from module `A` (call it `remotePath`), and use it within `require` in module `B`, then to get the full path inside module `B` we can use the following:

```
var path = require('path');
var fullPath = path.join(path.dirname(process.argv[1]), remotePath);
var moduleInsideA = require(localPath); // this now works
```

`process.argv[1]` gives us the module `A` start-up file, from which we take the directory path, and then join it with the remote relative path, which then gives us the full path.